# SQL Oracle: вывести сгруппированные подстроки определенной группы

Tags: sql, oracle

Просьба, подсказать, как более универсально можно вывести строки группировки,
допустим есть запрос

```
select col1, col2, col3, col4, col5 from table1
```

выполняю группировку:

```
select col1, col2, col3, sum(col5) from table1 group by  col1, col2, col3
```

как мне можно теперь получить строки группы где `sum(col5) > n` при этом в результате должны быть следующие колонки `col1, col2, col3, col4, sum(col5)`
т.е. найти определенную группу по колонкам `col1, col2, col3` и при условие вывести сгруппированные строки этой группы по колонкам `col1, col2, col3, col4`

Comment: Ну условие `HAVING sum(col5) > n`, а колонку `col4` присоединить это наверное `JOIN` этой же таблицы по совпадению столбцов `col1, col2, col3`

Comment: @CrazyElf, а возможно через оконные функции выполнить?

Comment: Наверное можно, я их плохо знаю

Answer (score 2, accepted):

С оконной функцией:

```
select *
  from (
    select col1, col2, col3, col4,
           sum(col5) over(partition by col1, col2, col3) as sum5
      from table1
  ) X
 where sum5 > n
```